# Include AND clause to query using AX AOT 2012

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, aot

I want to export query from sql to dynamics  so I create a AOT Query then I create view for it.

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT
TT.RECID,
TT.TRANSDATE,
TT.DATAAREAID,
TT.SOURCERECID,
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41)
```

I have all  query complete with `INNER JOINS` except for `AND` clause. How can I add AND clause using Query on AX 2012?

Current query:

[image: Query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a range (under the Ranges node) on the desired table for the field you want. You can specify multiple values for the range by using comma-separated values in the Value property of the range.